# setting the row height according to the size of the string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I want to change my height of the cell according to the content of the message string received. I am doing like this in side hieghtforrow delegate method of the table view.

```
int rowHeight =0.0f;

     UITableViewCell *cell = [ self.mtableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];

    CGSize size = [cell.textLabel.text  sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];// calculate the height 

    rowHeight = size.height+10; // I use 10.0f pixel extra because depend on font

    return rowHeight;
```

but it is not getting crashing in my application .Can anybody take a look on this?

Comment: Please post your cellforrowatindexpath method please.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? On a side note, since `rowHeight` is an integer, there's no need for the float literal constant

Comment: You shouldn't be needing to add the arbitrary value of `10.0f` to the calculated size to make up for any font discrepancy. Instead, you should be using `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0]` (use whatever font name your label uses, same for size). If you use the right font, the value you get from `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode:` should be the perfect value for the text size.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to understand how you are retrieving the text for the label.

You are on the right track with calling `sizeWithFont` but you need two things to determine this successfully:

1. The font size of the label (which you've hard coded at 13.0)
2. And the text to determine the size of (which you are trying to pull from the UILabel)

(Hard coded the font size in the code at 13.0 is not necessarily a good idea, because if you want to change it for the cell, you'll need to remember to change it in heightForRowAtIndexPath and wherever else, but that's a different issue).

Rather than pulling the text for the label from the `UILabel` itself, determine the text from whatever data structure you have that generated/contains the text in the first place.  That's why seeing your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method would be helpful.

Don't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` either, the methods are not intended to be used that way.

Here's a simple example, which I can refine when you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code:

```
//ASSUME that self.arrayOfStrings is your data structure where you are retrieving the label's text for each row.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int rowHeight =0.0f;
    NSString *stringToSize = [self.arrayOfStrings objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [stringToSize  sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 5000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    rowHeight = size.height+10;
    return rowHeight;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayOfStrings objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `UITableViewCell *cell = [ self.mtableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];`
 from your code. You dont need to add cell in HeightForRow method.

Comment: then how can i get the cell.textlabel.text

Comment: You need to write that code in cellforrawatindexpath not in heightforrow.

Comment: then according to wat i will adjust the hieght

Comment: hieghtforrow method returns integer so according to size rowHeight your hight of cell will be adjust and replace "cell.textLabel.text" to "your text"(print on that label).